# How to change css style in typescript?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript

In typescript how to change css styling just as I would do this way?

```
$(".s-hand").css("transform", "translate(-50%, -100%) rotate(" + s*6 + "deg)");
```

or

```
var hourPointer   = document.querySelector('.hour')
hourPointer.style[transform]   = `rotate(${hour}deg)`;
```

Because I have no idea how to achieve that..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has to be done like this:

```
let shand = document.getElementsByClassName('s-hand') as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;

if (shand.length != 0) {
  shand[0].style.transform = "translate(-50%, -100%) rotate(" + s * 6 + "deg)";
}
```